# Folland's real analysis, Theorem 5.29

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

In Folland's proof of theorem 5.29, it is probably obvious but I have difficulty in understanding the highlighted part:

[image]

Why does the completeness of $\{u_n\}$ imply $A=\bigcup_1^{\infty}A_n$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since $u_n$ form an orthonormal basis, the only vector $x\in H$ with $\langle u_n,x\rangle=0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ is $x=0$. (For this argument, it is in fact enough that $\{u_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is dense.)

Comment: By completness of $\mathcal{H}$ for every $x$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,u_n\rangle u_n$ is convergent. Since $\{u_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis there holds $$x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle x,u_n\rangle u_n $$In particular $$v_\alpha=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle v_\alpha,u_n\rangle u_n $$ Therefore $\langle v_\alpha,u_n\rangle \neq 0$ for some $n,$ i.e. $\alpha\in A_n.$